# determining area based on irregular border points

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

So say I am given a set of points:

```
0, 0
0, 5
5, 5
5, 3
4, 3
4, 2
5, 2
5, 0
0, 0
```

These points make up the border of a shape/object

The object looks like this:

```
 __________
|          |
|        __|
|       |__
|          |
|__________|
```

How can I mathematically determine the area? (in the example it would be 24..)

Additionally and more importantly, how can mathematically determine the x, y coordinates of each 1 unit by 1 unit box inside? (in the example, some of the boxes would have coordinates at (0,0), (0, 1), (0, 2) and so on...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shape is **convex**, you can break it down into triangles and then just sum the area of said triangles.

If the shapes are all rectangles (as in your example), then you just need sum the range between the start point and end point of each row.

If the shape is concave, then it's substantially more difficult. More information here:

http://math.tutorvista.com/geometry/concave-polygon.html

Comment: there is actually a simple formula for a polygon area that does not require convexity, known as the showlace formula:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula. The points do need to be ordered to form a polygon though.

Comment: That's kinda slick. Took me a bit to understand it, but I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically speaking if you only have the vertices, you can't. A collection of vertices does not per definition describe a unique polygon. To get this unique description of the object you also need the edges between the vertices. Only then can you be sure that you can calculate the surface area of the polygon defined.

So in your example you could solve this by defining edges only between two consecutive vertices in you vertex array. I do not know if this is the case in your situation.